# Moving a ball forward, mechanical force

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, keyframes

I'd like to have a ball (blender game engine) which rolls forward by its own and with real physics and friction.

It shouldn't be animated though, what I'd like to have is kind of like a "motorized ball" who rolls forward just by its own force. No work arrounds with wind or invisible objects pushing or draging it.

What I did:

- keyframes for the spinning animation (360 degrees)
- made it a rigid body
- sensors "always" and "action" so that it spins when in game mode

but it just falls down to the floor and spins where it is. It doesnt react to the floor whatsoever (which has collision on and is a passive).

Or is there a complete different way to do such things like "mechanical animation" or whatever it's called?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you tick the `Animated` checkbox?

Comment: Ouch, no, but now it rotates, falls to the floor but now I want it to move forward by its own, but it lyies just there, spinning but not moving forward...

Comment: Friction level?

Comment: that was it :) BUT the ball moves backwards instead of forward (it looks like a moonwalk), setting friction to 0 it again rotates on its place but at least bounces a bit up and down...

Comment: Are you SURE it is rotating the correct direction?

Comment: If that didn't solve it, upload the .blend file, if it did, let me know please.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The cube spins right but it goes left, it kind of floats, like a moonwalk. don't know how to solve this issue. friction doesnt do the trick.

Comment: Could you upload the .blend? Try [**this site**](http://pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: I found the solution yesterday. Need to tick the box "force" and then it behaves like it should. See here:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?359128-Why-does-this-cube-slide-backwards-%28Rigid-body-rotation-physics%29
Thx for the help.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I couldn't help you more with the issue . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tick the *Animated* checkbox under the *Rigid Body* tab:

[image]

If the object just sets there and doesn't roll, you should make sure your *Friction* levels are set properly for the involved collision objects:

[image]

Zero friction will result in no forward movement, make it higher and the "Stickiness" gets higher while lower settings make it more slippery.